# How to call onchange on dropdown via jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I've a jquery plugin created called 'testInfo'. here is the snippet:

```
$('#loadtest-info').testInfo({
            width: 400,
            title: 'Test Info',
            data:{
                name: nameInfo,
                status: statusInfo,
                region: regions,
                start: starttimeInfo,
                end: endtimeInfo,
                selectRegion:function switchRegion(){alert('')}
            }
        });
```

I have a dropdown that I need to perform a change event on: below is my underscore template

```
'<div class="test-info" id = "test-info"><dt class="label">Region:</dt><dd class="value"><% if ( data.region.length == 1 ) {%><%= data.region %>'
       +' </select><% }%><% if( data.region.length > 1 ) {%><select id = "selectedRegion"><% _.each(data.region,function(field){ %><option value ="<%= field.id%>" <%= (field.select) ? "selected" : "" %>><%= field.name %></option>'
       +'<% }) %></select><% }%></dd><dt class="label">Start:</dt><dd class="value"><%= data.start %></dd><dt class="label">End:</dt><dd class="value"><%= data.end %></dd></dl></div></div>',
```

I want to call the onchange event via my plugin. I tried something like this:

```
var self=this;
this.element.find('#selectedRegion').change(self.data.selectRegion)
```

there is no way i get this work. Anyone has ideas on how can I call the change event internally via plugin. I'm avoiding the use of external calling of the selector: i.e. `$( "#selectedRegion" ).change(switchRegion);` below is the entire code for my plugin:

```
(function ($) {

$.widget('wpm.testInfo', {
options: {
    data: {
        name: "",
        status: "",
        region: "",
        start: "",
        end: "",
        selectedRegion:''
    },
    title: "Test info"
},

_temp:  '<div class="test-info" id = "test-info"><h3 class="info-title"><%= title %></h3>'
       +'<div class="region-table" id ="region-table"><dl> <dt class="label">Name:</dt><dd class="value">'
       +'<%=data.name %></dd> <dt class="label">Status:</dt><dd class="value test-status"><%= data.status %></dd><dt class="label">Region:</dt><dd class="value"><% if ( data.region.length == 1 ) {%><%= data.region %>'
       +' </select><% }%><% if( data.region.length > 1 ) {%><select id = "selectedRegion"><% _.each(data.region,function(field){ %><option value ="<%= field.id%>" <%= (field.select) ? "selected" : "" %>><%= field.name %></option>'
       +'<% }) %></select><% }%></dd><dt class="label">Start:</dt><dd class="value"><%= data.start %></dd><dt class="label">End:</dt><dd class="value"><%= data.end %></dd></dl></div></div>',

_create: function () {
    this.element.addClass('loadtest-info');
    this.element.html(_. template(this._temp,{title:this.options.title,data:this.options.data}));
},

setStatus: function(status){
   if (status){
    this.element.find('.test-info').find('.test-status').text(status);
   }
},

destroy: function () {
   this.element.removeClass('loadtest-info');
   this.element.empty();
}

});})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for `.trigger('change')`?

Comment: Well, I'm looking for the change event that occurs when I select an option from a dropdown and onselection, it performs some action(in thi case its alert).

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS:

```
var selected = document.getElementById('selectedRegion');
selected.addEventListener('change', function() {alert('something')}, false);
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectedRegion', function() {
    alert('something'); 
});
```

Comment: This is still calling the change event externally. How can i make it call via my plugin. I have a 'selectRegion:function switchRegion(){alert('')}' within the my plugin testInfo. how can i call change event using that field.

Comment: Inside of your actual plugin code, store a variable reference to `this`. Example: `var testInfo = this`. Still within your plugin code, use `$("#selectedRegion", testInfo.element).change(function() { alert('something') });` Let me know if that works

Comment: If you want to actually `trigger` the change to occur, try `switchRegion() { $("#selectedRegion", testInfo.element).val(something).change(); }`

Comment: I tried using your earlier code to implement it in my plugin.js file. however I'm not sure as to what is the scope you are defining for     $("#selectedRegion", testInfo.element).change(function() { alert('something') }); Can you please provide with the example i have above??

Comment: Can you post your plugin code? Or enough to see what's going on?